The equivalent for 'renderEvent' method from v3 to fullcalendar v6
I currently transitioning to fullcalendar v6.
I cannot find the equivalent of 'renderEvent' method from v3 to v6. And also the '$.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, "yyyy-MM-dd")'
I added this code on the drop function
drop: function(date, allDay) {
  var dataStr = new Array()
  dataStr.push({
     name: "calendar_event_title"
     value: $("#calendarInput").val()
  });
  dataStr.push({
     name: "calendar_date_start",
     // v3 this got error, tried calendar.formatDate(date, "yyyy-MM-dd")
     value: $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, "yyyy-MM-dd") 
  });

  dataStr = $.param(dataStr);

  // post to server as new calendar event
  $.ajax({})
  .done(function(data) {
      if ( data.success ) {
       var event = data.event;
       var eventDataObj = {
           id: event.id,
           title: event.id + " : " + event.title,
           start: event.start,
           end: event.end
       }
       var originalEventObject = eventObject;

       //we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
       var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
       
       //I use the code below from v3 which got error, fullCalendar not a function
       $("#calendar").fullCalendar("renderEvent", copiedEventObject, true);

       //I tried the code below, but it duplicates the event display 
       //with '46 : august 8 event' at the top while 'august 8 event' at the bottom
       $("#calendar").addEvent(copiedEventObject, true);
      } 
  });
}


Most likely a problem with the copiedEventObject. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing & https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent

@nbokmans, I just updated with more code issues is no the formatDate which is still in v3 and on the addEvent that I tried.

You can read about date formatting in v6 here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting . FullCalendar isn't a date library. In the past it just leveraged moment.js under the hood. Now it's decoupled from that specific dependency. If you want date formatting functions to use outside of fullCalendar itself, beyond that the built-in JS Date object provides, then the logical thing to do is use a 3rd-party date library

And $("#calendar").addEvent cannot possibly work at all in v6 (or in v4 or v5). FullCalendar isn't a jquery plugin anymore. As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent It should be calendar.addEvent (unless you named your calendar object something different when initialising the calendar)
